# Slow SAP Data Services export to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, performance, sap-data-services

We've a MySQL 5.1 server and we are trying to import data from SAP Data Services from another server. It works but it takes 3h!

We tried to setup an Oracle XE server to test the same operation and it takes only 10 minutes.

I think the problem is that with Oracle the "Rows per commit" setting (1000) works ok, but with MySQL every row is committed. Is it possible? How can we solve it?

**Screenshot of the exporting settings**

[image: Screenshot of the exporting settings]

Answer (score 0):

SAP BusinessObjects Data Services (BODS) allows you to control the number of rows per commit, if data flow ends with a data store in your MySQL server

BODS includes an optimisation PDF guide as part of the help documentation - check that for other recommendations.